# When does the Gypsies racial ability come into play?

Tags: small-world

Do you collect the coins at the end of the Gypsy player's turn, or at the end of the game round?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Gypsies ability](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_gd_rules_en.pdf) states:

> "Place 1 bonus Victory coin (taken from the Victory stash) in each Region you abandon. You cannot conquer these Regions again this turn, but **you receive the coins they hold as a bonus at turns end**".

At the start of your turn, you place coins in each Region your Gypsies occupy. At the end of the Gypsies turn, collect all coins in those Regions that you don't occupy and return the remaining coins if any to the Victory stash.

The [rules state](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_2_en.pdf) a turn ends after troop redeployment and Victory coin scoring.

> 1. Picks a Race and Special Power combo
> 2. Conquers some Regions
> 3. Scores some Victory coins

Gypsies essentially allows you to score a Region for one additional turn after abandoning it, because Gypsies are always on the move.

> #### Abandoning a Region
>
> "Only those Race tokens that were taken back in hand may be used to conquer new Regions. If a player wishes to free up some more Race tokens, he may opt to entirely empty up some - or all - Regions, leaving no Tokens there; **but in this case, these now abandoned Regions will no longer be considered his, nor bring him any Victory coins.**"--*Small World rule book pg. 6*

Comment: @Darvanen you didn't finish reading the answer. He was rephrasing it in a different but equivalent way because the official description can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

While it is worded a bit strangely, it happens at the end of the gypsy player's turn, just like all other scoring.